# How do I get a regex expression to capture "x dollar(s) and x cents"?

Tags: python, regex

For example I would like my regex expression to capture both "1 dollar" if there are no cents, or "2 dollars and 71 cents" in my text.
I currently have

```
'\d[\d]*( dollar(s)?)(?:\s*(and )\d[\d]( cent(s)?)\b)?')
```

and I have tested it out here
[regexr.com/67etd](https://regexr.com/67etd)
It seems to work there, but when I run it in python. What regex captures is

```
(' dollars', 's', '', '', '')
```

I apologize I am very new to regex, does anyone have any suggestions?

here is my python code:

```
import re

train = open(r"C:\Users\inigo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\all-OANC.txt", encoding='utf8')
# didn't have encoding lol
# opens the files
strain = train.read()
# converts the files into a string
train.close()
#pattern = re.compile(r'\$\d[\d,.]*\b(?:\s*million\b)?(?:\s*billion\b)?')
pattern2 = re.compile('\d[\d]*( dollar(s)?)(?:\s*(and )\d[\d]*( cent(s)?)\b)?')

# Finds all numbers which can include commas and decimals that start with $ and if it has a million or a billion at the end
#We need to find patterns so if it contains a dollar keyword afterward it will count the number




matches = pattern2.findall(strain)

for match in matches:

    print(match)
```

Comment: Show how you're using it in Python. It looks ilke you're just printing the capture groups, not what the entire regexp matches.

Comment: `re.findall()` just prints the capture groups if there are any. Make them non-capturing groups.

Comment: @Barmar I have posted my code. How should I change it?

Comment: LIke I said: use non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\b\d+\s+dollars?(?:\s+and\s+\d+\s+cents?)?\b
```

[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com/67eue)

Comment: The `[s]?` can be shortened to `s?`

Comment: The pattern matches ++ Just as a small note, for a match only, you can omit the outer capture group, omit the non capture group around `(?:dollars?)` as the group by itself has no purpose and as the match starts with a digit, you might also add a wordboundary to the start `\b\d+\s+dollars?(?:\s+and\s+\d+\s+cents?)?\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you for the tips! This is completely right, you don't need those two groups in the regex; I have updated the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
'(\d+ dollars?)(\s+and\s+\d{1,2} cents?)?'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your regexp:

```
\d[\d]*( dollar(s)?)(?:\s*(and )\d[\d]( cent(s)?)\b)?
       ^       ^ ^ ^^     ^    ^      ^     ^ ^ ^  ^
       |       (2) ||     +(4)-+      |     (6) |  |
       +----(1)----+|                 +-----(5)-+  |
                    +--------------(3)-------------+
```

these are the numbers of the different groups you can submatch.  You have six groups, numbered after the position in the regexp of the left parenthesis, so this explains that, under the input string you matched, you get only the thing you describe.
If you want the numbers, you need to add parenthesis to the subexpressions of interest, so you get them in some of the groups, this way:

```
(\d[\d]*)( dollar(s)?)(?:\s*(and )(\d[\d])( cent(s)?)\b)?
^       ^^       ^ ^ ^^     ^    ^^      ^^     ^ ^ ^  ^
+--(1)--+|       (3) ||     +(5)-++--(6)-+|     (8) |  |
         +----(2)----+|                   +----(7)--+  |
                      +--------------(4)---------------+
```

(now you got eigth groups) and you have to search for the dollars amount in group 1, and the cents amount in the 6th group.